# DateTimePicker minDate not showing the value from database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, datetimepicker

I have a bootstrap datetimepicker it is working fune but when i trying to show the value from my database it is not working win minDate in javascript.

test date from my DB is `$a = '2020-04-13';`

```
<div class="form-group">
                                <label for="effective_date" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Effective Date</label>

                                <div class="input-group date  col-sm-8" style=" width: 338px !important; padding-left: 15px !important;">
                                    <div class="input-group-addon">
                                        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control pull-left" name="dd_effective_date" id="datetimepicker5"  value="<?php echo $a;?>" placeholder="" >
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#datetimepicker5").datetimepicker({
    useCurrent: false, format: 'YYYY-MM-DD', minDate:new Date()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var mindata = new Date('<?=$a?>');

$("#datetimepicker5").datetimepicker({
    useCurrent: false, format: 'YYYY-MM-DD', minDate:mindata 
});
```